# Using variable from settings.py in layouts

Tags: django, jinja2

I am from PHP,Zend world and new to django python. It might be a dump question, but I tried several ways, it didn't work,  please advice me .

I am using jinja2 with Django 1.7. I am trying to put the '`APPLICATION_TITLE`' in `settings.py`

```
APPLICATION_TITLE = "My Application"
```

I want this value to be used in `layout.jinja.html` as the title

layout.jinja.html

```
<head>
    <!-- APPLICATION_TITLE should go below -->
    <title>{{ ???????????? }}</title>
</head>
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

**your_app/context_processors.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

def application_title(request):
    return {'APPLICATION_TITLE': settings.APPLICATION_TITLE}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "your_app.context_processors.application_title",
)
```

**layout.jinja.html**

```
<head>
    <title>{{ APPLICATION_TITLE }}</title>
</head>
```

Comment: EXCELLENT.good explanation. worked for me. it worked with small change, because I created the file `context_processors.py` in root, in the settings.py under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` tuple, we should omit the `your_app` app name namespace. it should be `context_processors.application_title",`